# reporting on email-to-case settings

Tags: reporting, administration, metadata

I have several hundred email-to-case rules already set up. I am trying to find an email-to-case rule that is setting a case field (case origin) to a specific value. How could I find this? IMHO the most efficient way would be to report of all the email-to-case records and filter by the value, however, I can not report on email-to-case. Is there a tool that will allow me to do this?

Comment: are you referring to Case workflow rules? Case escalation rules?  Case assignment rules?

Comment: I am referring to email to case rules. Where you get to set the forwarding address and select whether a field/s on the case is updated with a certain value/s.

Comment: OK, I take it you mean Email-to-Case Routing Information page - and you have many entries in the Routing Addresses under Email-to-Case Settings page?  Have you tried for the `origin value` in question, creating a bunch of diagnostic Task statuses, one per routing name?  Then you could do a report and locate the Routing Address(es) of interest.  Then, maybe disable the task statuses once you have your answer. I realize this is 'destructive' testing so perhaps as a backup plan

Answer (score 1):

I can't check/confim right now but have you tried using the debug logs? Under monitor in setup.

Edit:

Edit:
So I believe the object you are interested in is Email Routing Address? Looking in the Eclipse Schema builder I can't see the object so I don't think we have query access to it, so no reporting. Maybe it's possible to get to it via a meta data API call but I don't have experience of that.